# System firewall setting?

Tags: system, firewall

I travel and live with someone all the time. Cast is enabled across the system and it's too easy to inadvertently cast something... embarrassing (just a click and it's on the TV). I found this design okay when I used to live alone, but now this is an unwanted feature to me.

Android/Chrome developers didn't make a setting that disables Casting(how could they). I blocked mDNS port on my laptop, but I couldn't find a way to disable Cast on my Android phone. I know there are firewall apps that need root access. I don't want to install any apps or root my phone. Is there a way to change firewall settings on Android? An interface to Netfilter module(if Android uses this, that is) like `firewall-cmd` or `iptables`? A standard way preferably so I can use this trick on all the Android phones I purchase through my life!

Comment: There is `iptables` but it requires root access.

Comment: Might be able with ADB.

Comment: Something like https://blog.usejournal.com/adb-port-forwarding-and-reversing-d2bc71835d43

Comment: ADB doesn't run with root privileges. `adb reverse` or `adb forward` redirects ports between ADB (on PC) and ADBD (on Android). No firewall or NAT is involved.

Comment: mDNS broadcasts for Casting are generated by Play Services app. But blocking that (if your ROM supports) would block many other things including push notifications. Simple is to not use apps with Cast feature, or root your device.